# Is largest eigenvalue of Hashimoto matrix of a graph always real

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

I wonder if there are some results which guarantee that the largest eigenvalue of a Hashimoto matrix of a graph is always real (Hashmioto matrices are square but not symmetric, so in general there are usually some complex eigenvalues). I checked on some examples and it seems to be true, but I would like to know for sure.

If possible, I would like to know this for two cases: directed and undirected graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is shown using Perron-Frobenius theory.

For example, the introduction of [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.531.9769&rep=rep1&type=pdf) shows that the radius of convergence of the Ihara zeta function coincides with the leading eigenvalue of the Hashimoto matrix.

Alternatively, you could try to apply the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) to the Hashimoto matrix yourself. It works because the (extended version of) Perron-Frobenius theorem applies to any non-negative matrix.

This works whether the graph is undirected, directed, or contains multi-edges or self-loops.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the detailed answer!